# Logs rotating faster than cron batch job run interval

Tags: bash, logging

We have application logs that are rotated on a size basis, I.e. Each time the log reaches 1mb, the log file changes from abc.log to abc.log.201110329656, so on. When that happens, abc.log starts again from 0mb. The frequency of the log rotation is around 30 mins.

We have a cron batch job running in the background against abc.log to check for nullpointerexception every 30 mins.

The problem is, sometimes the log is rotated faster than the next batch job can run, causing the nullpointerexception to go undetected because the batch job couldn't get a chance to run.

Is there a way to solve this problem? No, I cannot change the behavior of the application logging, size, name or rotation. I cannot change the frequency of the cron interval, which is fixed at 30 minutes. However, I can freely change other things of batch job which is a bash script.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Please note that Batch tag is "used for Windows batch file questions". Don't use it just because your question have "batch" word in any part of it...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Batch is a word pertinent to Windows batch?

Comment: The "batch" tag is related to Windows batch. There is a "batch-processing" tag for other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much stated what the problem is:

- You have a log that automatically rolls when the log gets to a certain size.
- You have another job that runs against the log file, and the log file only.
- You can't adjust the log roll, and you can't adjust when the check of the log happens.

So, if the log file changes, you are searching the wrong file. Can you do a check against all log files that you've previously haven't checked with your batch script? Or, are you only allowed to check the current log file?

One way to do this is to track when you last checked the log files, and then check all those log files that are newer than the last time you did a check. You can use a file called `last.check` for this. This file has no contents (the contents are irrelevant), but you use the timestamp on this file to figure out when the last time your log ran. You can then use `touch` to change the timestamp once you've successfully checked the logs:

```
last_check="$log_dir/last.check"
if [ ! -e "$last_check" ]
then
    echo "Error: $last_check doesn't exist"
    exit 2
fi
find $log_dir -newer "$last_check" | while read file
do
    [Whatever you do to check for nullpointerexception]
done
touch "$last_check"
```

You can create the original `$last_check` file using the `touch` command:

```
$ touch -m 201111301200.00 $log_dir/last.check  #Touch date is in YYYYMMDDHHMM.SS format
```

Using a touch file provides a bit more flexibility in case things change. For example, what if you decide in the future to run the crontab every hour instead of every 30 minutes.

Comment: I assume that inside the do construct i can do a grep on "file" just like grep -r "xxx" file? Thanks!

Comment: @ChinBoon - Yes, you can do a `grep -r "xxx" "$file"` inside the _do construct_. The `-r` is for recursive, so I don't think you need that since you should be just pulling up file names and not directories. However, you might want a `-q` in the grep and then check the status of the grep to see if whatever you're grepping was in the file.

Comment: Thanks again David, your idea is genius, may i know how did this come across to you?

Answer (score 4):

`find(1)` is your friend:

```
$ find /var/log/myapp -cmin -30 -type f -name 'abc.log*'
```

This gives you a list of all log files under `/var/log/myapp` touched in the last 30 minutes. Let your cron job script work on *all* these files.

Comment: To take this further, can this prevent me from grepping files I may have already grepped previously?

Comment: No, not without further ado. Someone might simply `touch abc.log.20090101` and then you get issues two years old back. You can restrict the `-name`, e.g., with utilizing `date`, or you have to keep account of log files, that you've already greped.

Comment: `date` example: `find ... -name abc.log.$(date +%Y%m%d)'*'` finds only today's log files.

Comment: i like the idea of finding today's log files. However i can imagine a scenario where the cron job runs at 00:15, but the log was touched at 23:59 and it won't get picked up. ><

Comment: Yes, that's the "ado" part, unfortunately.